# add hirarchy of categories in products grid of visual composer

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I am using `visual composer -> post grid -> products grid`,I have select filter option to filter with product categories,but problem is that product categories does not display like hierarchy .It is showing like

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3
- subCategory 1
- subCategory 2

I want to show it like

- Category 1

  -- subCategory 1
- Category 2

  -- subCategory 2
- Category 3

Even I tried to edit the code

```
if ( 'dropdown' !== $atts['filter_style'] ) {
    echo '<ul class="vc_grid-filter vc_clearfix vc_grid-filter-'
    . esc_attr( $atts['filter_style'] )
    . ' vc_grid-filter-size-'
    . esc_attr( $atts['filter_size'] )
    . ' vc_grid-filter-'
    . esc_attr( $atts['filter_align'] )
    . ' vc_grid-filter-color-'
    . esc_attr( $atts['filter_color'] )
    . '" data-vc-grid-filter="'
    . esc_attr( $atts['filter_source'] )
    . '"><li class="vc_active vc_grid-filter-item"><span data-vc-grid-filter-value="*">';
    echo esc_attr( $filter_default );;
    echo '</span></li>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li class="vc_grid-filter-item"><span'
        . ' data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-'
        . $term->term_id
        . '">';
        echo esc_attr( $term->name );
        echo '</span><!-- fix whitespace
        --></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

please help me , thanks in advance